# TypeError: conversion from Series to Decimal is not supported when applying function pandas Series

Tags: python, dataframe, formatting, decimal, series

I have the following function that converts values to a `Decimal` object:

```
def convert_to_decimal(value: str | int, decimals: int) -> Decimal:
    divisor = 10 ** decimals
    return Decimal(value) / divisor
```

I want to apply it to the values in a column of a `DataFrame`. `df['numbers']` is simply a `Series` object with `int` and `NaN` values in it.

My current code is:

```
df['numbers'] = df['numbers'].apply(convert_to_decimal(value=df['numbers'],
                                                       decimals=18))
```

But I get the following error:
`TypeError: conversion from Series to Decimal is not supported`.

I simply want to mformat every number in my `df['numbers']` into a Decimal object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 changes:

1. Call `apply()` on `df[['numbers']]` which returns pandas.DataFrame instead of pandas.Series.
2. Convert direct call to function `convert_to_decimal` to a call from lambda function.

```py
df[['numbers']].apply(lambda row: convert_to_decimal(value=row['numbers'], decimals=18), axis=1)
```